# Can '15 Prayers of St. Bridget of Sweden' be divided and prayed through the day?

Tags: catholicism, prayer, meditation

Can '15 Prayers of St. Bridget of Sweden' be divided and prayed through the day? What about '7 Prayers of St. Bridget of Sweden', can they be likewise divided? Prayers mentioned are full of content, and it is hard to meditate on every prayer. God Bless!